# Titanium- android- alloy project build error

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have create a simple alloy project using titanium studio. by File--> New ---> mobile project-->Defultalloy projects.

Then i tried to run on device oremulator.

getting the error like this.

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[INFO] :   Found Alloy app in E:\Mopl_WorkSpace\2013\titanium\WORKSP1\testAlloy\app
[INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: alloy.cmd compile E:\Mopl_WorkSpace\2013\titanium\WORKSP1\testAlloy\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test
[INFO] :   ----- MVC GENERATION -----
[INFO] :   [index.xml] view processing...
[INFO] :     style:      "index.tss"
[INFO] :     view:       "index.xml"
[INFO] :     controller: "index.js"
[INFO] :     created:    "Resources\alloy\controllers\index.js"
[INFO] :     created:     "Resources\alloy\styles\index.js"
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   [app.js] Titanium entry point processing...
[INFO] :     created:    "Resources\app.js"
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   ----- OPTIMIZING -----
[INFO] :   - alloy.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\backbone.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\constants.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\underscore.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\widget.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\controllers\BaseController.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\controllers\index.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\styles\index.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\sync\localStorage.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\sync\properties.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\sync\sql.js
[INFO] :   - alloy\sync\util.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\CFG.js
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 0.97891s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[INFO] :   Running build process:  python "D:\Software\android-sdk-windows\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\android\builder.py" "install" "testAlloy" "D:\Software\android-sdk-windows" "E:\Mopl_WorkSpace\2013\titanium\WORKSP1\testAlloy" "com.t.j" "16"
  File "D:\Software\android-sdk-windows\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\android\builder.py", line 141
    print "[DEBUG] Signal %s received. Terminating the logcat process." % signum
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: Have you tried building from CLI? `ti create -n "appName" -t app`. Then switch to that directory and type `alloy new`. See if you get the same problem.